# Set all values of a sub-index in Pandas based off a cross-section

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm relatively new with Pandas, and decided to punish myself by jumping right into multi-indices, and unsurprisingly could use some help.
In short, I'm trying to use a cross-section (xs) to take the values in my 'n' column and copy them into the 'n-1' column.

Here's how I set up my dataframe:

```
INTERVALS = ['1min', '5min', '15min', '30min', '1h', '4h', '1d']
ALL = slice(None)
rows = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']
col_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(y, z) for y in INTERVALS[::-1] for z in ['n', 'n-1']])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[x for x in rows], columns=col_idx)
```

This sets up a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       1d        4h        1h      30min      15min      5min      1min     
        n  n-1    n  n-1    n  n-1     n  n-1     n  n-1    n  n-1    n  n-1
row1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
row2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
row3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

So, I first tried to set just the "n" columns for row1, by doing this:

```
df.at['row1', (ALL, 'n')] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Which outputs this:

```
       1d        4h        1h      30min      15min      5min      1min     
        n  n-1    n  n-1    n  n-1     n  n-1     n  n-1    n  n-1    n  n-1
row1    1  NaN    2  NaN    3  NaN     4  NaN     5  NaN    6  NaN    7  NaN
row2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
row3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

NOW... if i use `n = df.xs('n', level=1, axis=1)` to just look at the 'n' sub-index, I get a simple output that looks this...

```
       1d   4h   1h 30min 15min 5min 1min
row1    1    2    3     4     5    6    7
row2  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
row3  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Awesome!
This is where I'm stuck though.
How do I take this xs df above and copy it into the `n-1` column for all rows?
I've tried tons of approaches with no luck so far... for example, `df[(ALL, 'n-1')] = df.xs('n', level=1, axis=1)` will give me an "unhashable type slice" error.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Comment: Is this what you are lookin for? `df.loc[:,(ALL,'n-1')] = n.to_numpy()`

Comment: That definitely works! Thank you. I never would have figured that out. Time to research to_numpy()...

Comment: one thing to remember with pandas is that any assignment would not work if the keys (column names or row index) doesnot match , since pandas aligns on index, if you are assigning something of the same shape but with different keys, use the underlying array :)